# UIScrollView ignoring constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, constraints

So, I have a view controller with an image, two labels, and another image. The labels resize to fit the text I set for them - I am trying to keep each item equally space from the one above and below it. Everything works fine except for my last image.

The last image has mode Aspect Fit, because I want it to shrink down to fit whatever screen it is on (this part works well, I think). Constraints currently set to 8 for leading, trailing, and vertical to label above it; for bottom constraint, greater than or equal to 20 to bottom margin (based on something I saw in a tutorial.)

The problem is, when I run the simulator, my final image is way way lower than everything else, rather than directly below the label. There is also a huge chunk of space after the image until the bottom of the screen. Why is this happening given that it is set to be 8 below the label?

[simulator scrolled slightly below label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JPGD.png)

[simulator scrolled even lower to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Pis.png)

Comment: have you put your all labels and Imageview directly on scrollview ?

Comment: Well, I have view > scrollview > another view > labels and image. I can try to put everything directly on scrollview and see what that does

Comment: No, this is right way what you have done.

Comment: Okay. I am fairly positive the problem is with the aspect fit mode - what I wanted was for the image height to automatically size itself based on the given width of the view + the image scale. (Basically I wanted it to scale itself down based on the width.) When I give the imageview a set height, the image no longer jumps way to the bottom of the screen, and is still scaled. It's not exactly what I wanted but it works.

Answer (score 0):

try to give constraint from superview not from margin. whenever you give constraints from margin change it with superview. second thing try to set bottom equal to 20 not greater or equal. (according to assumption of your constrains)

your constraints should be like below(my suggestion ) :

scrollview - leading,trailing,top,bottom

Containerview - leading,trailing,top,bottom, fix height, horizontal center in container

Labels & Image : leading,trailing,top and fix - height (if you want variable size height in image then dont give height but give bottom with superview with greater and equal or only equal)

Hope this will help :)